# Mongoose: value not incrementing through $inc

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have been struggling with this issue for days. For some unknown reason, a specific field ("reviewCounts") is not incrementing no matter what alternative methods I try.

Here is my Schema

```
let itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        rank: Number,
        image: String,
        name: String,
        title: String,
        count: Number,
        category: String,
        ratings: Object,
        reviewCounts: Number,
        reviews: Array,
        tags: Object,
    })
```

and this is the update method:

```
Item.findOneAndUpdate({name: item,title:title}, {
     $inc:{"reviewCounts":1},
     $set:averageQuery,
     $inc:query
     },{strict:false},
     function (err, data) {
     }
}
```

`$inc` works completely find on "query" not it does not increment "reviewCounts". I have tried using `$set` to manually set the value, but that did not work too. I doubled-checked and confirmed that the field is `int32` as intended. What could be the reason behind this issue?

Comment: Can you try with single `$inc` like `$inc:{ ...query, "reviewCounts":1 }` ?

Comment: @mickl It worked! Thank you! Could I please know the reason why your method worked?   Does mongoose not allow multiple $inc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build your update statement this way:

```
{
    $inc:{"reviewCounts":1},
    $set:averageQuery,
    $inc:query
}
```

you're duplicating the `$inc` key in your JavaScript object. JavaScript interprets such code as:

```
{
    $set:averageQuery,
    $inc:query
}
```

so simply last usage of particular key "wins" thus you loose the `reviewCounts` part.

You need to make sure that there's only one `$inc` and you can use the spread operator to combine your `$inc`'s:

```
$inc:{ ...query, "reviewCounts":1 }
```